# Deploying ADAM

Tags: adam

I need to have a way to deploy ADAM store to other environments in a couple of different ways.

1. Full backup and restore: take all contents from one environment and restore all in another environment
2. Partial backup and restore: take all contents for a particular OU (Organisation Unit) and restore at the same location in another environment. To expand a bit more, I have OU called "MyCompany" directly under the root and I would like to backup all the contents udner "MyCompany" and restore to the same position on another environment.
   FROM O=Root,OU=MyCompany on Server 1
   TO   O=Root,OU=MyCompany on Server 2

Any idea how I can do this?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the command line LDIF utility. Simply export then import.